# int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) AND file input

Tags: c

I've never used,

> int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

For most programs, I usually just compile in terminal (using mac) using two separate C files, example…

> gcc functions.c main.c

But now I need to use int main(int argc, const char * argv[])… I just don't know if I'm using it correctly. Heres some code…

I compile in the command line doing…

> gcc main.c input.txt

terminal tells me…

> ld: file too small for architecture x86_64
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

*NOTE* my functions work (i tested without using file input) and are in main.c also… i just didn't include them in this post. Also, node  is just a basic node struct to a linked list.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
FILE *input;


input = fopen(argv[1], "r");


node *list = malloc(sizeof(node));
char *string = malloc(sizeof(char)*1023);

fscanf(input, "%s", string);

//convert a string to linked list
list= sTol(string);

//print the linked list
printList(list);

return 0;

} // end main()
```

Am i completely wrong? the input simply contains one line that says 'hello'. All I'm trying to do is read that into my program and print it just to verify I'm reading my input correctly.

Comment: When you say you've never used `main(int argc, const char * argv[])` I hope you mean you never used a `main` function taking command line arguments? I.e. you have only used `int main(void)` before?

Comment: Umm, why are you doing `gcc main.c input.txt`?

Comment: don't use gcc after compiling... you have executable file after it - run it: `./a.out input.txt`

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing *compiling* your program (which is what `gcc` does) with *running* your program (which is when your program's `main` function gets command-line arguments).

Comment: `int argc` is the function argument that tells the `main` function how many arguments your program received when it was started (like a command `ls -l`. You can then find those arguments in `char **argv`. The names seem abstract, but just read them as saying _ARGumentCount_ and _ARGumentValues_, hence argc and argv. Passing a text file to a compile isn't going to work...

Comment: yes, I've never used a main taking command line arguments. why am i using,  gcc main.c input.txt? idk, thats what i've done before using two different C files to run my program from the command line, then just send my .a/.out to a txt file.  How should run using the input.txt from the command line?

Comment: thanks for the responses, Ill try it out.

Comment: thanks again, got it right. Sorry for such a basic question, but I did some searching for a while and just couldn't find a good answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not like a perl script or shell script, where you run

```
perl main.pl input.txt
```

With a compiled language like C, you first compile the program into an executable

```
gcc main.c -o myprogram
```

and then run the executable with the input file

```
./myprogram input.txt
```